# Can't import node-fetch into Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to import `node-fetch` into my `Typescript` project but I fall into this error:

> [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module : /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js require() of ES module is not supportes.

This is my setup:

1. node: v16.1.0
2. typescript: 4.5.2

The `node-fetch` package is imported in my project as followed: `import fetch from 'node-fetch';'`

This is my `tscongif.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "sModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [ 
      "src/@types/",
      "node_modules/@types",
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "config/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I tried alse to add `"type": "module"` into the `package.json` and set `"module": "ES2020"` into the `tsconfig.json` but I got a new error:

> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

To run my code I use `nodemon` configured as follow:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts, js, json",
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node -T"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing these errors?

Comment: In my console... Using `nodemon ./src/server.ts` where `nodemon` is configured as: `{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts, js, json",
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node -T"
  }
}`. 

For a more readable version, see the question

Comment: @jsejcksn Sorry, I forgot to tag you -.-

Comment: It seems that your problem is related to configuration in tooling in your repository. You'll need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, imagine that the person wanting to reproduce your issue only has `node` and `npm` installed. You'll need to provide all the files and steps needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @jsejcksn Here you can find a reproducible example: https://github.com/riccardo-nigrelli/node-fetch-problem

Comment: Thanks, I'll clone it and write up an answer after I diff what needs to be modified.

Comment: Run `yarn add encoding` in your project directory, to be honest it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is not a problem in your application code, but is caused by project misconfiguration. ESM support in `ts-node` is currently experimental. See this GitHub issue to understand the current situation:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007

According to the data in the [repo link](https://github.com/riccardo-nigrelli/node-fetch-problem) you shared in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063451/cant-import-node-fetch-into-typescript?noredirect=1#comment123857996_70063451), along with the information in the above issue and the documentation notes [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/tree/3a2848c9968f03f7b05e57e833ca256b52ab4e18#other), the following changes will allow you to run your app using the npm `start:dev` script in the reproduction repo.

---

`./package.json`:

**Add** the following entry to the top-level of the object (this will tell Node that your transpiled `*.js` files are ES modules and to run them in that mode):

```json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

---

`./tsconfig.json`:

**Modify** the value of `compilerOptions.module` to `"esnext"` (this will tell TypeScript to emit modules in ESM format instead of CJS):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

---

`./nodemon.json`:

**Modify** the value of `execMap.ts` to the following (configuring the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable this way enables native ESM support in `ts-node`):

```json
{
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "NODE_ENV=development NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' ts-node -T"
  }
}
```

---

Console output:

```
$ npm run start:dev

> fetch-problem@1.0.0 start:dev
> NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./src/index.ts

[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,js,json
[nodemon] starting `NODE_ENV=development NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' ts-node -T ./src/index.ts`
(node:3273) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
START
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: Run `yarn add encoding` in your project directory, to be honest it resolved my issue.

Answer (score -6):

node-fetch from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require(),
according to doc.

did u tried using this:

> import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';

Comment: Yes, I also tried with  `import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';` but the problem persist :(ù

Comment: did u tried using require and which version you are using ?

Comment: version of what? If the version of `node-fetch` I'm using the `3.1.0`. With the `require()` the error is the same

Comment: try this config 
`{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2015",
      "lib": ["es2017"],
      "declaration": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "removeComments": true,
      "inlineSourceMap": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["scripts/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "node_modules/lodash-es/**/*.js"]
  }`

Comment: It's not work... Same error